# Label and input inside the same border

Tags: html, css

i have 2 labels and two inputs, as the picture shows:

[image]

How can this be done? i'm using external css file.

Html code:

```
<fieldset class="polje">
            <legend>Podatki</legend>
            <dl>
              <dt id="border1">
                <label id="ime_label" for="ime">Ime</label> 
              </dt>
              <dd id="border1">
                <input type="text" id="ime" tabindex="1">
              </dd>
              <dt id="border2">
                <label for="priimek">Priimek</label>
              </dt>
              <dd id="border2">
                <input type="text" id="priimek" tabindex="2">
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </fieldset>
```

Comment: I need to create a border as the picture shows. So...first label and input have their own border, so does second label and input. And legend too.

Comment: I'm having trouble with creating a border around two elements(label, input). I only managed to create a border around each of them, which is not correct. I can't post the code since i get en error that I use forbidden words.

Comment: You have multiple ID's. You should change these to classes, you can only have one ID with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/YJVek/

```
div {
    border:solid thin #000;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
}
h2 {
    margin:-15px 0 0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    width:80px;
}
label {
    margin-left:10px;
    width:60px;
    float:left;
}
p.border {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-top:solid thin #ccc;
    border-bottom:solid thin #ccc;
}
```

Comment: This could work yea, but I can only add "id" nad "class" elements to html code, since it is a school assignment and was preformatted.

Comment: Well you can use the same concept and apply it to your markup easily enough.